# Planning table relation in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, database-design, phpmyadmin

Good day, i need help on how to plan tables in phpmyadmin. This site has

table for users: username, password, email, phone, country, state, city, address, etc

table for comments:comment1, comment2, comment3, .... (these comments are on differnt pages)

the idea is, when a user logs in, he or she will comment. i want a way to plan the tables so that when a user comments, it will insert record into the comments according to the userid.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add a PrimaryKey `userId` to your `users` table and Foreign Key `userId` to your `comments` table. Then you can grab the `userId` from the user who is logged in and write it with the according comment to your table.

For Example:

table for users: `userId, username, password, email, phone, country, state, city, address, ...`

table for comments: `userId, comment1, comment2, comment3, ...`

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you say each comment is tied to a particular page and user, I would recommend that you structure your comments table as:

`user_id, page_id, comment_id`

Each comment from each user on a page will then have a corresponding row in the table. This structure will make it much easier to manage adding new pages or re-ordering your existing pages if you need to do so.

Comment: Ok. Now that i have 4 pages, with hundred questions each, do i do it this way?                                                                                                                                         Users table:username, password, email, phone, country, state, city, address.------> page table: page_id, comment_id, comment1, comment2, .... please how do i go about it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Is there one comment on each page, or does each page have several comments? Please update the question to explain how you're expecting the interface to work.

Comment: each page have several comments. i want it to be in such a way that when a user with id of 3 comments on comment1, comment_id will be automatically set to 1.